# Finding point coordinate using Python in QGIS

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, qgis-plugins

How can I find point coordinate in Python vector layer in QGIS? I need to define xy to a variable.

Comment: Do you need XY-coordinates as a new attribute using PyQGIS?

Comment: I need to declare the xy values ​​of a point to the variable

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As an example, you can use the following structure:

```
point_layer = iface.activeLayer()

for feature in point_layer.getFeatures():
    point = feature.geometry().asPoint()
    x, y = point.x(), point.y()

    # OR
    # xy = [point.x(), point.y()]

    # Do whatever you want with x and y of each point feature
```

Or you can get a point feature by `id`:

```
feature = point_layer.getFeature(0) # 0: id of the point feature

point = feature.geometry().asPoint()
xy = [point.x(), point.y()]
```